# Using React.memo instead of memo directly gives undefined error. Valid for any react hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite

I'm trying to write a small test for a react component that uses a `memo` hook.
When running jest to run the tests, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memo')

  13 | };
  14 |
> 15 | export default React.memo(SomeComponent);
     |                      ^
  16 |
```

I'm importing react using `import React from 'react'` statement at the top of the module.

If I'm importing the hook directly there, like `import React, { memo } from 'react'`, it works as expected. Importing as `import * as React from 'react'` works as well.

Running the app works fine and everything is normal, this happend only when running the tests with jest.

This is valid for any react hook.
What could be the reason for this?

The app is created using `Vite` and is using `Typescript`, `Jest` and `@testing-library/react`, while also using `ts-jest` as transformer.

Comment: `jest` is known to have problems with imports. I tried to find similar issue, but i failed. My advice is to just not using the default import

Answer (score 2):

`memo` is not the same as `useMemo`

`memo` is for wrapping a functional component for memoization, whereas `useMemo` is for memoizing a value inside a functional component

Comment: My bad, i wrote it wrong. Changed the description.

For this particular case, it's about `memo`, but using any other import from `react`, like `useMemo` or `useCallback` gives the same error.